# How to get Steam ID by username using Python?

Tags: python, steam

I want to get steam **ID** by **user name**
using Python.

I tried the following code, but it prints only user names.

and i read the docs -> python-valve.readthedocs.io/en/latest/steamid.html
but i cant understand.

```
import valve.source.a2s
import valve.steam.id
import steam
import valve
import time
import a2s
import pymysql

Server_IP = ""
ServerPort = 0
Server_IP = input("Server IP : ")
ServerPort = input("Server PORT :")

SERVER_ADDRESS = (Server_IP, int(ServerPort))
while(1):
    player_count = 1

    with valve.source.a2s.ServerQuerier(SERVER_ADDRESS) as server:
        info = server.info()
        players = server.players()
        steamUserid = server.__str__()

    print("{player_count}/{max_players} {server_name}".format(**info))
    for player in sorted(players["players"],
                        key=lambda p: p["score"], reverse=True):
        user_name = ("{name}".format(**player))

        if user_name == "":
            duration = "{duration}".format(**player)
            print("{:>2}".format(str(player_count)) + " | duration(sec) = " + "{:    <20}".format(duration) + " EpicGames")
            player_count += 1

        else:
            steam_name = "{name}".format(**player)
            duration = "{duration}".format(**player)
            print("{:>2}".format(str(player_count)) + " | duration(sec) = " + "{:    <20}".format(duration) + " Steam" + steam_name)
            player_count += 1

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: do you have documentation for this module? You could add link in question (not in comment)

Comment: you could use `print()` ti see what you have in variables - maybe there is ID. And `print(dir(...))` to see what methods/functions you have in object. Maybe there is function to get ID.

Comment: https://python-valve.readthedocs.io/en/latest/steamid.html

Comment: i aleary read this docs, but i can't understand.. help me.